GPU and CPU usage drops while in game
For the past two months I have had some problems with my fps in some games, while everything works fine in others. What I am experiencing is fps drops from a stable 120 down to around 30. Sometimes the fps goes back up to 120, sometimes it stays at 30. I built this computer around a year ago, and everything worked perfectly fine until maybe 2 months back. Here are my specs:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor 3.80 GHz
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT
Motherboard: Asus ROG Strix B550-F Gaming
RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX Black DDR4 3600 MHz 2x8GB
SSD: Crucial P5 Plus - PCIe 4.0 NVMe M.2 SSD 1TB
PSU: Cooler Master MWE Gold V2 Full Modular 750W
Monitor: AOC Gaming 25G3ZM
OS: Windows 10 Home ver. 22H2
Here is a video of my problem: https://vimeo.com/1038308368?ts=0&share=copy
After 4 seconds, you can see that the GPU usage drops from 60% to around 10%, and the CPU usage drops as well. This results in my fps going from 120 to 20. After 14 seconds I'm back at 120 fps. I don't know what's up with the GPU MEM CLK being max, but it is like that in all games (even those that works fine). In some games, the GPU usage constantly goes between 10 and 100 and so does the fps.

Have you done a full test of your system's cooling systems? Reapplied thermal paste? Checked temps to see if they correspond to these dips?

try lowering the resolution in game, also decrease filters, also if your mouse support polling rate might be the issue it can result in fbs drop if you have a high end mouse which have polling rate bottom which can be accidentally pressed, it also found in mouse software, make it 500 or less 
